# How to refactor a for loop with lodash _.filter vs _.forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop, lodash

I;m trying to implement lodash to refactor this for loop, what would BE THE best way to go for it ***_.filter*** or a **_.forEach** ?

```
for(var i = 0; i < origPam.length; i ++){
                if(origPam[i].editor.mapped !==newPam[i].editor.mapped){
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement your own digest? Anyway, as there are no breaks, `_.forEach` should be fine, so you won't create any new collection along the way.

Comment: I prefer the `filter`, `map`, `reduce` methods, they're simpler to code and tell you what is happening, unlike a vague `for` or `forEach`. Must you use lodash? Why not plain old JavaScript `filter`?

Comment: What's wrong with plain-old `forEach` that's been in JavaScript since it crawled out of the primordial tar pits?

Comment: @tadman sadly, primordial ooze only recedes at the dawn of IE9. That said, you can polyfill a happy foundation right over top of that tarpit, and live mappily ever after.

Answer (score 1):

Seem you have 2 input array. I will use `_.zip` to pair them first.

```
const pams = _.zip(origPam, newPam)
```

Then filter by condition.

```
const pamsToProcess = 
  _.filter(pems, ([origPem, newPem]) => origPem.editor.mapped !== newPem.editor.mapped)
```

Finally `_.forEach` to do stuff.

```
_.forEach(pamsToProcess, ([origPem, newPem]) => {/* do stuff */})
```

Combine above

```
_(_.zip(origPam, newPam))
  .filter(([origPem, newPem]) => origPem.editor.mapped !== newPem.editor.mapped)
  .forEach(([origPem, newPem]) => {/* do stuff */})
```

---

Because you cannot use `break` in `_.forEach`, you can use `_.takeWhile` to filter out things first.

Answer (score 0):

```
origPam.forEach(function(val, i) {
  if (val.editor.mapped !== newPam[i].editor.mapped)
    // do stuff
});
```

To be honest you should probably optimize this (there's no point calling $apply more than once)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `filter()` unless you plan on using the results. For example, you could use `filter()`, *then* use `forEach()` to iterate over those results, calling the method, or doing whatever else.

Or you could keep it simple and filter as the first step in the `forEach()` callback. Since you're not building results to use later, this might be the simplest approach.